Apache - Redirect www and non subdomain to the same page without getting 404 in TYPO3
So I have the following problem: When I use https://www.example.com as the domain, I get the content but when I use https://example.com I get the generic TYPO3 404 error page.
I tried setting up a redirect with example.com and .* as the source path and my starting page as the target and I also tried setting up baseVariants in the site config.
It's a bit strange that my normal base is just example.com and not www.example.com but www.example.com is the one that is working while the other one just gives a 404.
I need to reliable have https://example.com and https://example.com configured to get the same page.
I use TYPO v12.4.14 on an Ubuntu 22.04.4 with an Apache Webserver and PHP 8.1
[This is what I tried with the redirects. But that does not work because the regular expression has no delimiters. At least that is what I learned in the time since I made this post initially]
1
Edit 2:
I tried to make 2 vhosts to redirect example.com to www.example.com. Here are my config files:
File 1 example.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com

</VirtualHost>

File 2 example-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com

</VirtualHost>

Now it works for http:// example. com but not for https:// example. com
Note: I asked this before on stack overflow, and copyed it to here.
This is my default conf 000-default-le-ssl.config
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    # ServerName example.com

    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/Example/public/"

    <Directory "/var/www/Example/public">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
    </Directory>


    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf



Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


</VirtualHost>



Remove the Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com directive from your File 2 (example-ssl.conf) and add a rule to force www. in your URI.
Your example-ssl.conf configuration should look like this:
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    
    # Force www in URI 
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>

The RewriteCondition checks if the host is your domain and without www. If so, then it redirects to www.example.com. Because this is server side, your 404 error should disappear.
EDIT:
If the rewriting in the VHost does not work, then you can also move it to the .htaccess file in the Docroot.
The TYPO3 Default htaccess comes with a rewrite section. Must be located in line 300 round about. Should then look like this:
......

### Begin: Rewriting and Access ###

# You need rewriting, if you use a URL-Rewriting extension (RealURL, CoolUri).

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Enable URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Non www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

......


This does not work for me. I also tried adding this to the default ssl conf and that also does not work and gives me the typo 404 site config not found error.

You now need the site config for www.example.com

And your Server needs the mod_rewrite modul. You can check this in the php info.

Please first check if the rewriting works. If you type https://example.com in the browser, does it rewrite the URL to https://www.example.com?

No the rewrite does not work. @Mogens

Ok. Then first check of the mod_rewrite is installed and activated.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server

The rewrite module is one of the required modules for TYPO3. Check also the other required modules if you want to run TYPO3 on your Server: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html

TYPO3 works fine and rewrite ist active. But the one for the www.example.com adress does simply not work in my configuration. And i dont know why.

You could try to move the Redirect to your htaccess file.

I edited my answer

I think i need to test again on a different device in case its cached somewhere, but it seems to work now with the .htaccess file. Thank you

Testing in a new inkognito window of your Browser should also work.

Yeah i know, just wanted to be sure. And it totally worked on all my tests. Thank you again for your help.
